# How to install jsoncpp on CentOS 8

Tags: installation, centos, json, dnf, centos-8

I have tried:

```
$ sudo dnf install jsoncpp
Last metadata expiration check: 0:31:37 ago on Fri 17 Jul 2020 02:02:47 PM CST.
No match for argument: jsoncpp
Error: Unable to find a match: jsoncpp
```

And I know I could install jsoncpp from source code, but I just wonder what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jsoncpp` package is available in the EPEL repository.
Thus:

```
sudo dnf -y install epel-release
sudo dnf -y install jsoncpp
```

Comment: Thank you, this method works perfectly!